# Google Charts: How to customize the Date format displayed on the axis?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I follow the documentation on axes customization [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes) but it does not say how to customize the date format on the AXES, only on the columns.

I need my axes format to be "dd/MM/yy" but unable to achieve such a simple taks...

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/qBdgNYb?editors=1010)

```js
google.charts.load("current", {
  packages: ["line"]
});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Date", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
    [new Date(2006, 1, 1), 5394, 5014, 2480, 9380, 4852, 7128],
    [new Date(2006, 1, 8), 5697, 5147, 2480, 9187, 7644, 7134],
    [new Date(2006, 1, 16), 5780, 5192, 2480, 8941, 7729, 7148],
    [new Date(2006, 1, 25), 5993, 5211, 2480, 8750, 7768, 7151],
    [new Date(2006, 2, 2), 6207, 5282, 2480, 8636, 7827, 7195],
    [new Date(2006, 2, 11), 6334, 5361, 2548, 8515, 7874, 7140],
    [new Date(2006, 2, 16), 6687, 5346, 2566, 8347, 7895, 7131],
    [new Date(2006, 2, 28), 6967, 5398, 2802, 8220, 7831, 7141],
    [new Date(2006, 3, 1), 7061, 5419, 2818, 8198, 7827, 7031],
    [new Date(2006, 3, 2), 7335, 5457, 2829, 8211, 7959, 6966]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chart: { title: "my graph" },
    curveType: "function",
    legend: { position: "none" },
    axes: {
      x: {
        0: { side: "top", label: "axes label", format: "dd/MM/yy", color: "red" }
      }
    },
    hAxis: { format: "dd/MM/yyyy" },
    vAxis: { format: "MMM d, y" }
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById("curve_chart"));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div id="curve_chart"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several options that are not supported by *material* charts.
see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

*material* chart --> `google.charts.Line` -- `packages: ["line"]`

*classic* chart --> `google.visualization.LineChart` -- `packages: ["corechart"]`

---

for the options that are supported by *material* charts,
you need to convert those option to *material* options before drawing the chart...

```
google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options)
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load("current", {
  packages: ["line"]
});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Date", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
    [new Date(2006, 1, 1), 5394, 5014, 2480, 9380, 4852, 7128],
    [new Date(2006, 1, 8), 5697, 5147, 2480, 9187, 7644, 7134],
    [new Date(2006, 1, 16), 5780, 5192, 2480, 8941, 7729, 7148],
    [new Date(2006, 1, 25), 5993, 5211, 2480, 8750, 7768, 7151],
    [new Date(2006, 2, 2), 6207, 5282, 2480, 8636, 7827, 7195],
    [new Date(2006, 2, 11), 6334, 5361, 2548, 8515, 7874, 7140],
    [new Date(2006, 2, 16), 6687, 5346, 2566, 8347, 7895, 7131],
    [new Date(2006, 2, 28), 6967, 5398, 2802, 8220, 7831, 7141],
    [new Date(2006, 3, 1), 7061, 5419, 2818, 8198, 7827, 7031],
    [new Date(2006, 3, 2), 7335, 5457, 2829, 8211, 7959, 6966]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chart: { title: "my graph" },
    curveType: "function",
    legend: { position: "none" },
    axes: {
      x: {
        0: { side: "top", label: "axes label", format: "dd/MM/yy", color: "red" }
      }
    },
    hAxis: { format: "dd/MM/yyyy" }
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById("curve_chart"));
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div id="curve_chart"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

---

note: in the above chart, the y-axis contains numbers,
a date format will not work on the `vAxis`...

```
vAxis: { format: "MMM d, y" }  // <-- removed from above snippet
```

---

**EDIT**

when loading google charts, the default locale is --> `'en'`
to load a different locale, specify the language in the `load` statement...

```
google.charts.load("current", {
  packages: ["line"],
  language: "fr"
});
```

Comment: thanks, it helped, by the way, do you know as well how to change the language of the chart? (days of weeks to be displayed, say, in French)?

Comment: however, I didn't really understand why removing the vAxis helped to solve the problem on the Y-axis ))

Comment: the y-axis is represented by numbers, not dates. adding a date format to the y-axis when using the material options conversion will cause an error. -- as for changing the language, this is an option on the load statement, see __EDIT__ above...

Comment: great, following your answer I found the docuemntation about https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#loadwithlocale hovever it seems in order to change la chart language there is need to reload the library....